# React e Redux, chamada com dispatch ao reducer causando loop em componente baseado em classe

Tags: javascript, react, redux

Minha aplicação combina React e Redux

Tenho um componente baseado em classe chamado Login.js, um slice chamado settingsSlice.js e estou usando connect para acessar o estado nesse componente.

Meus arquivos:

**settingsSlice.js**

```
const initialState = {
    initial: initialSettings,
    defaults: _.merge({}, initialSettings),
    current: _.merge({}, initialSettings),
    themes: initialThemes
};

const settingsSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'settings',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        setSettings: (state, action) => {
            const current = generateSettings(state.defaults, action.payload);
            const themes = state.themes;
            return {
                ...state,
                current,
                themes
            };
        }
    }
});

export const { setSettings } = settingsSlice.actions;
```

**Login.js** (resumido para não ficar muito extenso)

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import axios from 'axios';
import { compose } from 'redux';
import { setSettings } from 'app/store/fuse/settingsSlice';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { withTranslation } from 'react-i18next';
import queryString from 'query-string';

const customStyles = theme => ({
    root: {
        /*...*/
    },
});

class Login extends React.Component {

    componentDidMount() {

        let params = queryString.parse(this.props.location.search);

        if (params.idvisu) {
            this.getIdVisu(params.idvisu)
                .then(resp => {
                    this.props.onSetSettings(resp.settings);
                }).catch(message => {
                    console.log('ID Visual Error:' + message);
                });
        } 

    }

    getIdVisu = (idvisu) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            axios.get(process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL + '/api/idvisu/' + idvisu)
                .then(res => {
                    if (res.data.status) {
                        resolve(res.data.result);
                    } else {
                        reject(res.data.message);
                    } 
                });
        });
    }

    render() {

        const { t, classes } = this.props;
        const { idvisu_data } = this.state;

        return (
            <div>
                Formulario de login e UI...
            </div>
        )
    }

}

Login.propTypes = {
    classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return { 
        settings: state.settings
    }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        onSetSettings: (settings) => {
            dispatch(setSettings(settings));
        }       
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(
    compose(
        withTranslation('login'),
        withStyles(customStyles)
    )(Login)
)
```

**Explicação do que estou tentando fazer:**

No arquivo Login.js eu informo os dados que eu gostaria de resgatar através da função `mapStateToProps()` e quais ações gostaria de disparar através de `mapDispatchToProps()`.

Até ai, tudo funcionando bem, se eu rodar console.log(this.props) dentro do componente eu consigo visualizar os states que eu precisava e também a função onSetSettings.

O meu objetivo é se eu passar um parâmetro especifico via URL (params.idvisu), que o sistema carregue via request (API) as configurações que ele encontrou e salve elas no state do redux através da action onSetSettings.

Após a finalização da request, quando eu chamo a função `this.props.onSetSettings(resp.settings);` ele entra em loop e o React encerra o APP.

O que eu posso estar fazendo de errado? Se eu crio um botão e no onClick eu chamo essa função diretamente ela funciona, é somente quando eu tento chamar no componentDidMount que isso acontece.

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que o problema esteja aqui:

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(
compose(
    withTranslation('login'),
    withStyles(customStyles)
)(Login)
```

)

Se não me engano, o connect vai dentro do compose, assim:

```
export default compose(withTranslation('login'), withStyles(customStyles),
connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps))(Login);
```

Não sei se esse erro causaria o looping, porém, parece ser o único erro aparente, tenta arrumar e ver se corrige.